# Reskin or develop an outlook lookalike calendar as a web version

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, calendar

Has anyone created a web calendar with similar features to Outlook or iCal for Mac?

Enclosed is a mockup of the ideal calendar with Day, Week and Month.

Many thanks!

[image: Web Calendar]

Comment: Mmmm... Maybe more suitable for webapps.stackexchange.com? Or are you looking for a component to use in a web app?

Answer (score 2):

Use [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).  There are other jQuery plugin calendars out there, but FullCalendar has the most features and is definitely still under active development.

It looks different from your mock-up, but has day week and month views.  It's open source so you could certainly modify it to show such items as the week in year like you have on the side.

I have no affiliation with FullCalendar, but I've used it extensively and answered several FullCalendar related questions here on SO.  It's just a great tool.